# can my docker container app access the host's microphone and speaker? (Mac, Windows, Linux)

Tags: docker

I'm building a headless softphone application. I know I can build wss or web server with the given tools... but my web app needs to do some pjsip and other codec things with the host's speaker and microphone. Are these devices shared between the mac/windows/linux hosts and the docker container?

Comment: Have you found an answer how to configure this on windows?

Comment: This question was not so obvious 3 years ago as Containers seemed more like chroot and now it seems like something different. I'm inclined to remove this question mostly because it's not important anymore but it does answer the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had to use the microphone and speakers of the linux host from a docker container. Since in linux/unix based OSs devices are special files in the file system this solution should apply. In Windows it won't.

I discovered that the ubuntu image I was using in my container didn't have the ALSA drivers needed to use the soundcard. So after installing them in the docker container:

```
sudo apt-get install -y alsa-base alsa-utils
```

and running the docker image with the following parameters:

```
docker run --device /dev/snd:/dev/snd <container_name>
```

it worked. You can test if it works by invoking `aplay` and `arecord` inside the container.

Comment: could @atavio elaborate on the second command? why do we need to add /dev/snd:/dev/snd along with the --device switch? Thanks.
I can run aplay and arecord inside the container with no issues. i just want to be able to access the microphone of the host device?

Comment: The sound devices of the Linux host were there so I mapped them to the /dev/snd of the guest. Since docker is designed to abstract your application from the host's hardware configuration you need this device mapping.

Comment: How would I achieve the equivalent on Windows?

Comment: This is the correct answer! worked perfectly on raspberry debain

Comment: did someone succeed in doing that on Windows 10 as well?

Answer (score 1):

Never tried with speakers and microphone, anyway you can access host devices using the option `--device` in `docker run`.

See [Add host device to container (–device) in Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) for more details.