# OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device) in docker

Tags: python, docker, airflow, pyaudio, librosa

I have scheduled a task in Apache airflow that records audio and saves the recording locally. The input device is my laptop's microphone. Apache airflow is installed on docker and I'm using Windows OS. I get an error with this task(message mentioned below). When I run the script to record audio locally, it runs perfectly. I guess there's some problem while accessing the input audio device from within docker. Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem would be helpful.

Error message

```
[2023-08-30 08:31:45,841] {taskinstance.py:1482} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1138, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1311, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1341, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 117, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 128, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/dag_save_recording.py", line 48, in save_recording
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 639, in open
    stream = PyAudio.Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)
[2023-08-30 08:31:45,850] {taskinstance.py:1532} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=dag_save_recording, task_id=save_recording, execution_date=20230830T081323, start_date=20230830T083145, end_date=20230830T083145
[2023-08-30 08:31:45,896] {local_task_job.py:146} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Comment: This could maybe help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700653/can-my-docker-container-app-access-the-hosts-microphone-and-speaker-mac-wind