# docker container: audio open error: Device or resource busy

Tags: docker, ubuntu, audio

I pulled latest ubuntu image, installed alsa packages following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700653/can-my-docker-container-app-access-the-hosts-microphone-and-speaker-mac-wind).

I entered the bash in interactive mode and did:

```
arecord -d 5 -f U8 test.mp3
```

I get:

```
Recording WAVE 'test.mp3' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
```

but when I'm trying to play this recording with:

```
aplay test.mp3
```

I get:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
aplay: main:831: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

Listed devices:

```
root@6b3c0ed7f11e:/# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CS8409/CS42L42 Analog [CS8409/CS42L42 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 13: HDMI 7 [HDMI 7]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 14: HDMI 8 [HDMI 8]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 15: HDMI 9 [HDMI 9]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 16: HDMI 10 [HDMI 10]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 17: HDMI 11 [HDMI 11]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
root@6b3c0ed7f11e:/# arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CS8409/CS42L42 Analog [CS8409/CS42L42 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I started container with command:

```
docker run -it -d --privileged --device /dev/snd:/dev/snd ubuntu
```

Does my computer keep the microphone busy?
Is there a way to fix it?